# Flexbox grand-child cannot set height as a percentage of parent's in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I am making a website that makes use of the `flexbox`. I have discovered a difference in the Firefox and Chrome implementations. To me, it seems like Chrome has incorrect behavior.

The issue is this. Let's say we have a `div` with `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row`. This div contains two children `c1` and `c2`. Both `c1` and `c2` will have the same height, which is the maximum height needed to fit the content in either child. If we add a child to `c1` (say `c11`), then this child (`c11`) cannot set its height as a percentage of its parent's (`c1`). In Firefox, this works fine. Here is a fiddle illustrating the difference (open in Firefox and Chrome):

https://jsfiddle.net/9pyn2urq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hypothetical example, you need to create a new flex context for `c1`, and add  `align-items: stretch`.

```
.c1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;  
}
```

I modified your fiddle so that it uses these new rules. Also note that in the modified example, I remove `height: 100%` on `#insideFlexy`, since its parent, `#flexy1`, uses `align-items: stretch`.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/yo3x5bw5/